# Massive (Belated) Congratulations to Stephen Kitt!

Tags: discussion

Better late than never I hope, but huge congratulations to [stephen-kitt](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/79/stephen-kitt) on hitting 100k in reputation this year. Of course at this point he's sailed beyond that to 114k.

It's a considerable achievement, so thank you for being such a great contributor to the site!

Answer (score 15):

Thanks Matt! It’s been a pleasure contributing to this site.

Comment: It's folk like you that make it work! When I put in the Area 51 proposal I full thought it'd mostly be around technical questions for those still using retro machines, but instead it's been way more interesting, with excellent anecdotes and real curisoity pieces coming out.

Answer (score 7):

Stephen Kitt, you are one of the most valuable and reliable sources I know - especially when it comes to x86 and PCs. Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge.

Also thank you for your patience when I miss to see the finer detail of your replies. RC.SE wouldn't be the same without you.

Comment: Thanks, that means a lot to me coming from you! And huge congratulations on your 200k ;-).

Comment: @StephenKitt Thank you.